# The simplies CountDownLatch in the world doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

Why 3 threads can run `Worker.run()` when the `CountDownLatch` is set to 1 and it is decreased in every thread.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(1, latch));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(2, latch));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Worker(3, latch));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("end");

    }

}
```

.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Worker implements Runnable {

    int x;
    CountDownLatch latch;

    public Worker(int x, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.x = x;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        latch.countDown();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println(x);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not using the CountDownLatch correctly.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown()):

> countDown()
>   Decrements the count of the latch, releasing all waiting threads if the count reaches zero.

You are using the wrong method! You have to use `await()` if you want these threads to block. That method should be used to *sync* on the latch. Count down ... just counts down.

In other words: you have three threads trying to count down the latch. Your one call to `await()` happens **after** all three threads have done that! In that sense: turn back, and study the API that this class gives you - and then rework your example to do something "useful".

Answer (score 0):

@GhostCat give you technical aspect of your problem. If you use await you still do not synchronize anything. Question is what you are trying to do. If you try to write code to execute workers run methods one by one, you should synchronize code inside run method on same lock like this (or oyu can use semaphore with one permit):

```
Object lock = new Object();
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(1, object));

public class Worker implements Runnable {

    int x;
    Object lock;

    public Worker(int x, Object lock) {
        this.x = x;
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized(lock){
           enter code here
        }

    }

}
```

If you only replace countdowns by await and opposite, you will get same result as before changes.